# Question at the end of a sentence

Tags: questions

During a conversation in chat I wanted to say

> Your current version of the project is not bad. The question is how good you want it to be.

And then I thought: Is it right to use the question without question mark and inversion?
I read and heard a considerable amount of English and the phrase seemed okay, but I wasn't completely sure.

Based on [this](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/question-mark.html) info, I finally decided that it was right.

Am I correct?

Comment: Maybe, **"The question is: how good do you want it to be?"**

Comment: @SovereignSun, I assume that this is the option, but my question was about correctness of the aforementioned phrase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the question to not hang around for an eternity without an answer,

Yes, it is possible to phrase the sentence in that way.

An example of a similar case is given in the [recording](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oYmqJl4MoNI) of Bryan Lockwood getting streets 1:12.

> Do you see how fast my pace is?

Answer (score -1):

Sounds ok to me.
The main meaning of *question* is *query* but in this sentence the word *question* has the same meaning as *matter*.